# How to add agents to a queue in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm trying out Team Services and I see that I can add queues but I can't add any agents to them. In fat, I had two starting queues: Default and Hosted and only the latter had an agent in it.

1. Are agents necessary for enabling automatic builds or am I a victim of misconception?
2. How do I do more agents to the queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Add more Hosted Agents, which as of this writing cost $40 each, you also have to have an Azure account and have it linked to your Visual Studio Team Services account.

Assuming your VSTS and Azure accounts are linked, log in to the new Azure Portal, go to All Resources and search for **Team Services Account**. Select your Team and then choose the option **Build And Deployment service**. The first option that shows up is Hosted Agents which defaults to 1, and you can increase up to 5 per pool.

Comment: This is adding "Hosted Pipelines".
Microsoft says
 "
 Concurrent processing within a single build or release does not require additional concurrent pipelines. So long as you have enough agents, you can
 In a release process, deploy to multiple environments at the same time."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/licensing/concurrent-pipelines-ts

So how do I add more "Agents" ?

Comment: For hosted pipelines, the count of hosted agents you can use at given time, seems to always be the same, as the count of pipelines. I found no documentation on this, but have experimented with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be depending on Microsoft to provide the agents, use the Hosted queue. You can't add machines to the hosted queue, the idea there is that agents are provisioned on-the-fly for your builds.

For other queues, you need to install and configure an agent on a machine (whether on-prem or in Azure/AWS). For Windows machines, there's a download link right on the agent pool screen.

For non-Windows machines, you can install the [Node.JS build agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent) from NPM.

Comment: Given that I don't want to pay additional money for this laboratory try, I guess I can't use the downloaded agent. I'll have to rely on the default one.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You can download the agent and configure it against a pool (Default if you don't want to add another pool) and it will work even for the free version.

For hosted pool, you will be able to use the 1 hosted agent with a limit of 30 mins per build/release

Comment: @daniel-mann "You can't add machines to the hosted queue, the idea there is that agents are provisioned on-the-fly" - this doesnt happen for us - we have 17 builds pending and more hosted agents aren't being provisioned on the fly. I think you have to manually add more Agents but as the OP mentioned there isn't an obvious way to do this.