# VSTS limit of hosted pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We're using hosted agent pipeline/pools on VSTS. We've set the hosted pipelines count to 10. It's not enough for our needs, so I tried increasing the count, but the [web UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/acquisition?itemName=ms.build-release-hosted-pipelines&acquisitionOption=2) for this does not allow me to (and a [dead link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=703830) shown there, which is supposed to explain on how to raise the limit).

Is there any official article or documentation mentioning this limit? Is there a way to remove that limitation or at least raise it?

The only mention on such a limit, which I've found was in one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37425363) to a Stack Overflow question (on how to add agents to a queue in VSTS), and it mentions that 5 is the max (which is obviously an out of date information). It does not provide any source reference.

We are aware of the private pipelines / private build agents (which seem to have the limit set at 1000 and the same [dead link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=703830) to explain how to raise it). We are using those, but for this particular case, switching from hosted to private is not a viable option.

**EDIT (2018-06-27):**

Microsoft staff has mentioned the limit on the page of "[Microsoft-hosted CI/CD](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-hosted-pipelines)" service in [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), on the "[Q & A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-hosted-pipelines#qna)" section in March 2018:

> Currently, we have a hard limit of 10 Hosted pipelines. If more hosted
>   pipelines are needed, customers have to contact us and we will
>   increase the limit. Since, hosted pipelines come with a dedicated
>   azure agent, we have a check on the maximum anyone can buy and for
>   those accounts with the need for higher number of hosted agents, we
>   would like to allot them on case by case basis. We are currently
>   planning to increase the upper limit for Hosted Pipelines. You can
>   contact us here: "RM_Customerqueries at microsoft dot com" with your
>   account details and the number of hosted pipelines you need. We will
>   increase the hosted pipelines for you.

Although it mentions a way to increase the limit, a later question (2018-06-26) from another person states that it does not seem to work:

> Is there an updated process for requesting more than 10 hosted agents?
>   Getting "undeliverable address" responses to the email listed in a
>   reply below from March.

**EDIT (2018-12-31):**

In the meantime I've tested a suggestion posted on UserVoice and have filed a support ticket via Azure Portal. This worked (after some clarifications) - the hosted agents pipeline limit was raised for our VSTS (currently Azure DevOps) account.
In the meantime, the page for ordering the agents was tweaked, so now it explains, that you should contact support (and has the mentioned previously link pointing to the Azure DevOps support page).

Comment: You can mail this concern to RM_Customer_Queries (at) microsoft (dot) com. Looks like a bug to me and they are pretty responsive.

Comment: Do you have any reference, to which you can point me, where it would mention, that there's no limit or the limit is different? It does not look like a bug to me, unless you are just referring to the dead links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit a user voice here: [Hosted pipeline limit](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33450451-hosted-pipeline-limit)

Comment: Voted. This would suggest, that the limit official. Any docs on this?

Comment: Do not find related official article.